# Should translated English keywords pointing to local language landing page be in a separate Campaign / Ad group or same as original?

Tags: google-search, advertising, google-ads, ppc, sem

We have done quite a bit of testing with driving local traffic using English terms (eg. used cars Stockholm) instead of local language terms (begagnade bilar Stockholm). Basically, English keywords have been leading to an English language page and Swedish keywords to a Swedish landing page. However, the conversion rate for the English language pages have been more than 4x lower than the local language pages. Thus, we are planning to direct the English keyword traffic to a local language page instead so that "used cars Stockholm" and "begagnade bilar Stockholm" are leading to the same landing page. Right now, we have separate campaigns and ad groups for the two keywords. Is that the way to go or should we place "used cars Stockholm" in the same ad group as "begagnade bilar Stockholm"? The current structure we have is as follows:

```
Account: Sweden
Campaign: Stockholm
Ad group: used cars Stockholm
Keywords: "used cars Stockholm", [used cars Stockholm], +used +cars +Stockholm
```

Would it then be better to have it as follows:

```
Account: Sweden
Campaign: Stockholm
Ad group: used cars Stockholm
Keywords: "used cars Stockholm", [used cars Stockholm], +used +cars +Stockholm, "begagnade bilar Stockholm", [begagnade bilar Stockholm], +begagnade +bilar +Stockholm
```

Or as its own campagin / adgroup?

Any suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: I would personally choose to have them in the same group, though I'm not a professionst and I'm also interested about the topic, will watch for other ansewars

Answer (score 0):

From [campaigns overview AdWords documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/campaigns-overview) (emphasis added):

> Items that can be set at the campaign level include bids, budget, **language**, location, distribution for the Google Network, and more. Large advertisers typically create separate ad campaigns to run ads in different locations or using different budgets.

Targeting different languages should generally be done in separate campaigns.

As far as ad groups go, different landing URLs should get separate ad groups.

You want to separate your different language keywords and landing pages into separate ad groups in separate campaigns.
It is up to you as to whether